# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt' (no module named c)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pip, anaconda

Trying to run some code for a GUI which occasionally works if I run it as a notebook file (other times it attempts to compile and nothing happens).

Im trying to run it as a .py file and I get an error where module "c" is trying to  download but fails because "requirements.txt" doesn't exist.

Im using anaconda(gl-env)2.7 as my project interpreter and have attempted to install/find the requirement.txt file using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get the error that the file/directory doesnt exist.

When I run my program this is the error I get:

```
Collecting c
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/5f/1130c201f3138745970f8de520095a942cdd174e8f84faf04ce77c434d8d/c-0.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Tommy\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\c\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        with open('requirements.txt') as fh:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the `PKG-INFO` for this module:

```
        ## Installing

        This is a python 3 package, and requires python 3.5.
        To install, type in the terminal:

            pip3 install c
```

Doesn't look like you can use this for 2.7. As a note, I did not pip install, I just ran

```sh
curl --output c-0.1.0.tar.gz https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/5f/1130c201f3138745970f8de520095a942cdd174e8f84faf04ce77c434d8d/c-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

to download the tar archive

Comment: I'm just confused as Im only trying to run a program that is striclty using tkinter which is compatible with 2.7. I have no idea what c even is and why its collecting it.

Comment: `c` is a third party package, to quote from it's documentation: "This is a battery history analyZer for android and compatible systems". Does this install when you attempt to install `tkinter`?

Comment: Tkinter was already installed as a base package when i downloaded pycharm. I'm using jupyter notebook on pycharm and Tkinter works fine there but when running tkinter in a .py file thats when it throws the error about the C package.